# Set individual maxAge for sessions when using cookieSession() in Connect/Express

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies, node.js-connect

I am trying to use Connect/Express `cookieSession()` in order to store my node.js sessions in cookies (and thus, avoiding a server-side session store). This would help me to 'remember' the user when they log in and keep sessions alive even after server restarts.

I would like to do this with `cookieSession()`:

```
app.use( express.cookieSession( { secret: 'secret_key' } ) );
app.use( function (req, res, next) {
    if ( req.method == 'POST' && req.url == '/login' ) {
      if ( req.body.remember ) {
        req.session.cookie.maxAge = 30*24*60*60*1000; // Rememeber 'me' for 30 days
      } else {
        req.session.cookie.expires = false;
      }
    }
    next();
});
```

However, this does not work, because req.session.cookie is undefined. I also tried the following, but it didn't seem to work:

```
app.use( express.session( { secret: 'secret_key' } ) );
app.use( function (req, res, next) {
    if ( req.method == 'POST' && req.url == '/login' ) {
      if ( req.body.remember ) {
        req.cookies['connect.sess'].maxAge = 30*24*60*60*1000; // Rememeber 'me' for 30 days
      } else {
        rreq.cookies['connect.sess'].expires = false;
      }
    }
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting out with

```
app.use(express.cookieSession({ secret: config.server.cookieSecret }));
```

And changing it to

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  express.cookieSession({
    secret: config.server.cookieSecret,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: req.param('remember') ? 20000 : 3000
    },
  })(req, res, next);
})
```

So, we create our own middleware, wrapped around the cookieSession middleware, changing the maxAge based on a param.

So, whenever you change the session you'll need to pass a `remember` in the `body`, `query`, or `params`( that's where `req.param()` looks ).  In most cases, you only set a `user_id` to the session once, at login.

It's 3 seconds or 20 seconds to test and ensure it works.

And again, it might be not very helpful if you're setting stuff to your session a lot, but if you just set a user_id to session at login, this is all you need.

If you are setting lots of stuff to your session, you should know that data get passed around at every request, and you should save only the minimum to the session, like user_id, then look up the data you need for each request, to keep the overhead down on the user.

Comment: I don't know about the `cookieSession` middleware but be aware that if you try to do it like this using `express-session` you'll leak EventEmitters, because the call to `session({..})` sets up listeners every time it is called.

Comment: @Sam are you sure this is still true?

Comment: I haven't checked recently but that was happening for me in December.

Comment: Yea, looking back on this, it doesn't seem like a great idea.  I'd probably create a new `expresss.router`, one for each of the params, then route to each one depending on the param

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want:

```
// Using express.session instead of express.cookieSession
app.use(express.session({ secret : 'secret_key' }));

app.use( function (req, res, next) {
  if ( req.method === 'POST' && req.url === '/login' ) {
    if ( req.body.remember )
    {
      req.session.cookie.maxAge = 30*24*60*60*1000;
      // needed to make the session `dirty` so the session middleware re-sets the cookie
      req.session.random = Math.random();
    }
    else
    {
      req.session.cookie.expires = false;
    }
  }
  next();
});
```

`cookieSession` does some funky stuff, like `del req.session.cookie` (not sure why).

Comment: I have actually tried that, but the session is not saved to the cookie (session gets destroyed when server is restarted). cookieSession, on the other hand, is persisted even between server restarts.

Comment: You're right, I misinterpreted the results of my testcase. `express.session` by default will use the MemoryStore which resets when the server is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first set `req.session.cookie` so that you can set `maxAge`. Trying to use it before you set it gives `req.session.cookie is undefined`

`express.cookieSession` has default values which it accepts, see [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#cookieSession). You should mention all the parameters you are going to use. You can set cookie via the following :

```
app.use(express.cookieSession({ secret: 'secret_key', cookie :{ path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: 30*24*60*60*1000} });
```

Comment: That sets the maxAge for ALL session cookies, but I don't want that. I want the maxAge to be set ONLY when the Remember me option on the login form is checked.

Comment: to set use req.session.cookie={ secret: 'secret_key', cookie :{ path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: 30*24*60*60*1000}}

Comment: That doesn't really work. I tried using `req.session.cookie={ secret: 'secret_key', cookie :{ path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: 30*24*60*60*1000}}` in my `if (req.body.remember)` block, but it didn't set the cookie correctly - when I closed the browser and opened it again, I was logged out.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the table but I thought this answer may help people going forward...

I was using *cookie-session* which doesn't create a cookie object on `request.session`. To properly implement rememberMe functionality using `request.session.cookie` I switched *cookie-session* to *express-session* and that solved everything. So now there is a cookie object on session and doing this inside of a request is possible...

> npm install express-session

```
app.post('/login', function(request, response, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if(err) return next(err);
        if(!user) {
            request.flash('loginMessage', info.message);
            return response.redirect('/account/login');
        }

        request.login(user, function(err) {
            if(err) return next(err);

            if(request.body.rememberMe)
                request.session.cookie.maxAge = 2592000000;
            else
                request.session.cookie.expires = false;

            return response.redirect(options.redirect);
        });
    })(request, response, next);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also pretty late but it might help other people.

It seems like to me the best way to persist your session data is to store it in something like redis. The question asked for a way that didn't use server storage, but I think he was referring more to MemoryStore. Maybe not but either way this is what I did.

I used express-session and connect-redis

```
npm install -g connect-redis
npm install -g express-session
```

Then you configure stuff.

```
// session modules
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session')
var redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session); // this sets up Redis to work with your session cookies
var app = express();
```

Then you just initiate your session with the store option set to your redisStore.
The maxAge part sets the lifetime of each session to an hour, the session middleware resets it when it's accessed.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({ 
    store: new RedisStore({
        host:'127.0.0.1',
        port:6380,
        prefix:'sess'
    }),
    cookie: {maxAge: 3600000 },
    secret: 'session_secret' 
}));
```

Now when a client connects, express should store the session data automatically in a Redis data structure. Since it's not just cached in memory, your server can crash and still have all the relevant session data still available at the IP address and and port specified.

Answer (score -1):

[Yummy](https://github.com/shtylman/node-yummy) seems to allow modifying cookies expiry after creation.